# MAMP Virtual Host Returning 'It Works!' page

Tags: localhost, mamp, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I have kind of come to my wits end with this. Earlier tonight my MAMP stopped working once I attempted to restart it. So I decided to uninstall and reinstall MAMP and see if that helped. However it's caused something else that has never occurred before.

If I type localhost in the address bar, it returns 'It works!'. I created a virtual host as I had done before, to what seemed step by step as I had previously, however, it also returns the dreaded 'It works!' page. I have followed tutorials and no one else has seemed to have this issue. I had no idea what I have done incorrectly here. Any advice would be massively appreciated.

Below are the files I have altered

## hosts

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       portfolio
```

## httpd.conf

Uncommented the following line

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

## httpd-vhosts.conf

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/Library/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/Library/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/portfolio"
    ServerName portfolio
</VirtualHost>
```

What have I done wrong here?

Going to `http://localhost:8888/` & `http://localhost:8888/portfolio` work as expected but `localhost` & `portfolio/` do not.

Comment: did you solve this problem? I got the same thing

Comment: You need to change the ports. Mamp uses 8888 by default, but your configuration specifies 80. That's why your sites work on 8888 but not 80. Once you switch back to 80 things should start working as expected again.